# VS code BeautifulSoup4 issue: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I got error when ran a flask app. This project includes **scraping** so I installed BeatifulSoup4 in python virtual env. When I ran flask, I got error.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

But I installed BeautifulSoup4 correctly. `pip3 install beautifulsoup4`

There is a weird thing.
When I wrote at terminal, it imported bs4 successfully.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you tried the import bs4 in same environment ?

Comment: Yes. I am sure. I created only one env.

Comment: how did you run flask

Comment: export FLASK_APP=main.py           flask run

Comment: I might suggest running code in Docker rather than the text editor

Answer (score 1):

You have to install bs4 package for running beautifulsoup4. If you install only beautifulsoup4, then it won't work as you are using the following import:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Also, it won't work because BeautifulSoup is the sub-package of bs4.